# What are some static and dynamic characteristic we can get from probe inclinometers?

Tags: geotechnical-engineering

I'm currently doing a work about probe inclinometers but I need to know which soil characteristics we can ger from the inclinometers.

Comment: what is the result of your research? ... how does it fail to answer your question?